# ShapeDrawable is not drawing properly when given as background

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

My Current view looks like this:

[image: My current view with 'MyHouses']

I tried to draw a shape drawable with this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Outer green rectangle-->
    <item
        android:bottom="140dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ff5500" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="180dp"
        android:bottom="140dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <!-- inner white rectangle -->
    <item
        android:bottom="-10dp"
        android:right="90dp"
        android:left="90dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-85">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size
                    android:width="30dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and I managed to get this shape:

[image: Shape using ShapeDrawable]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry3nf.png)

The problem is that when I give this shape as a background of my layout, it looks like this:

[image]

Where as my final goal is to make it look like this:

[image]

Comment: can u try this answer

Comment: I will surely! In next couple of days and update you

Comment: I tried your answer but it gives me an orange rectangle, like the one above in original pic (current view).

Answer (score 0):

change your drawable file like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Outer green rectangle-->

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff5500" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="-720dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="-85">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>


    <!-- inner white rectangle -->

</layer-list>
```